# The new Ubuntu 13.04 for Hadoop

Tags: server, hadoop

I am a beginner both on ubundu and Hadoop. Can I have ubundu 13.x for hadoop..what is the latest version; do I need use.. If Ubundu 13.x is not recommended; what is the stable version I can use..and what is the Hadoop version required..Please suggests me.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Still stable version is ubuntu 12.10, I thing it's good for beginner, otherwise you can use Ubuntu 13.04 but it's a testing version, while you are using it may be appear some bug, Ubuntu 13.04 is now latest version, and now have to download Ubuntu 13.10 Daily Build, I will recommend for you Ubuntu 12.10